# Some problems with installing Appium

Tags: python, node.js, appium

I tried to install Appium by writing `npm install -g appium` into Python terminal. An error occurred: "node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".
Below I present my console logs.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g appium
C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm\authorize-ios -> C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\.bin\authorize-ios
C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm\appium -> C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js

> appium-selendroid-driver@1.13.4 install C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-selendroid-driver
> node ./bin/install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\appium\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-selendroid-driver@1.13.4 install: `node ./bin/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-selendroid-driver@1.13.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-23T12_10_51_490Z-debug.log
```

EDIT:

I did what you suggested:

```
C:\Users\MarcinPilzak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>python -m pip install appium
Collecting appium
```

And I got such error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement appium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for appium
```

Answer (score 1):

To install libraries with Python, you need to navigate to your Python folder wherever that may be. Then go to /Scripts and copy the directory. 
Now go to command line and do:

```
cd <paste copied directory here>
```

Then do:

```
python -m pip install appium
```

This should work. If not, let me know.